# Kick off async method in constructor in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, reactivex

I'm wondering is it safe to call async method in a constructor in the following way:

Let's say we have an async method **Refresh** that is fetching data from the internet.  We are also using **Reactive Extensions** to notify everyone that is interested that new data was fetched.

I'm wondering is it safe to call **Refresh** first time in a class constructor? Can I use such construction?

> Task.Run(Refresh);

or

> Refresh().ConfigureAwait(false)

I'm not really interested here if the method has finished or not, since I will get notified through **Reactive Extensions** when data is fetched.

Is it ok to do something like this?

```
public class MyClass
{
    BehvaiorSubject<Data> _dataObservable = new BehvaiorSubject(Data.Default);
    IObservable DataObservable => _dataObservable;

    public MyClass()
    {
        Refresh().ConfigureAwait(false);     
    }

    public async Task Refresh()
    {
        try
        {
           var data = await FetchDataFromNetwork();

           _dataObservable.OnNext(data);

        }
        catch (VariousExceptions e)
        {
           //do some appropriate stuff
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
           //do some appropriate stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to do this, I'd suggest an async initialisation method that you can call instead.

Comment: I second DavidG. Adding: If you absolutely want to construct _and_ kick off the fetch, you could use a(n async?) Factory Method, that creates the instance, kicks off the fetch, then returns the instance.

Comment: Stephen Cleary has written [some interesting articles about async construction](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) that I think you would find useful.

Comment: No. Refresh is not static, however is belongs to a class that is a singleton. I have few ViewModels that are observing this singleton. I'm looking for an easy way to start this Refresh for a first time when user launches application.

Comment: @Matthew Watson Thank you. I've looked at it and indeed those are good alternatives. However they require more work and those approaches assumes that I need to wait for initialization to finish. But in my case I think I do not need to wait. I just need to fire of my method and continue.

Comment: I've tested both approaches I posted in question and they seem to work on my machine, but I'm not sure if they will work everywhere.

Comment: override Application.OnStart and call Refresh from there

Comment: If this is bad I would really appreciate if you could tell me why is it bad? I'm sitll learning :)

Comment: @DavidG Unfortunately my instance is being constructed by IoC container. So I can't do async construct without changing application logic...

Comment: It is bad because you are loosing control about how and when the initialization starts/ends. When the app grows and you have to init more and these init has to be in a special order then you are lost with your approach

Comment: _"Unfortunately my instance is being constructed by IoC container"_ - why "unfortunately"? You can indeed use Factories and/or FactoryMethods with DI. What is in use here? Something Xamarin-Specific?

Comment: @Sir Rufo Hmm.... Yes, this is good argument. However I'm still not sure if I really need to know when "initialization" finish. Basically this is not an initialization. Object state is valid even if Refresh will fail (in example becouse no internet connection). However I need to take under consideration what you said and think about it. Thank you.

Comment: @Fildor Hmm... This way... I see now. OK. You are right. This might work. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though people are against the idea, we have similar things in our project :)

The thing is you have to properly handle any exceptions thrown from that `Task` in case they go unobserved. Also you might need to expose the task via either a method or a property, just so that it is possible to `await` (when necessary) the async part is finished.

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        InitTask = Task.Delay(3000);

        // Handle task exception.
        InitTask.ContinueWith(task => task.Exception, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }

    public Task InitTask { get; }
}
```

Comment: I see... Thank you very much for the answer. Basically inside my Refresh method I'm trying to handle all exceptions. Since I'm using Internet connection I expect various exceptions to be thrown.